# Is there a more concise way of including dependencies in RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, requirejs-text

Suppose I have a module that starts like the following:

```
define(['jquery', 'actions', 'util', 'text!../templates/dialog.html!strip', 'text!../templates/requestRow.html!strip', 'text!../templates/respondForm.html!strip'], function($, actions, util, tDialog, tRequestRow, tRespondForm) {
```

This module contains most of the code for writing to my client UI.  It also loads a couple other modules I've written as well as 3 HTML templates using the text.js plugin.  I'm wondering if there's a more concise way of doing this?  As the application grows, I may have additional templates to load, or modules and it just seems like my define statement could grow to be a bit ugly.  Should I just add my template paths to require.config in my main.js like this:

```
require.config({
baseUrl: '/webrequests/resources/scripts/',
paths: {
    'modernizr': '../js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min',
    'bootstrap' : '../js/vendor/bootstrap.min',
    'dialog' : 'text!../templates/dialog.html!strip',
    'requestRow' : 'test!../templates/requestRow.html!strip',
    'respondForm' : 'text!../templates/respondForm.html!strip'
}});
```

Is there perhaps some way to load all templates within a directory and just have 1 dependency to include in the define statement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a module for loading in the templates you frequently use. So group the templates to be loaded in one module, that way you can just load this *template* module instead of the individual templates:

```
// generalTemplates.js
define([
    'text!../templates/dialog.html!strip', 
    'text!../templates/requestRow.html!strip', 
    'text!../templates/respondForm.html!strip'
], function (tDialog, tRequestRow, tRespondForm) {
    return {
        dialog: tDialog,
        requestRow: tRequestRow,
        respondForm: tRespondForm
    };
});
```

So that in your module, you can simply include the templates like any other module:

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'actions', 
    'util', 
    'generalTemplates'
], function($, actions, util, templates) {
    var tDialog = templates.dialog,
        tRequestRow = templates.requestRow,
        tRespondForm = templates.respondForm;

    /* You can do stuff with the templates here */
});
```

Comment: Wow, I never thought of doing that.  That makes perfect sense!  Still kinda new to RequireJS.  Thanks!